# Python zip on two numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, indices

**The below is a working example, you can copy all the variables and run the `for` loop to check**

I have two lists, one of length = 13 and one of length = 7.

```
varying_DA = [70,78,86,90,94,98,100,102,106,110,114,122,130]
test_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13] #DUMMY array
varying_Hinv = [60,76,92,100,108,124,140]
```

I would like to loop through the above two lists, i.e. using two `for` loops like:

```
for vary_DA,test in zip(varying_DA,test_array): 

    for vary_Hinv,min_a,max_a in zip(varying_Hinv,min_aH,max_aH):
```

So in the above `for` loop, it starts with `70` for `vary_DA` and loops through the 7 values of `vary_Hinv`, i.e. 60,76,...,124,140. Then goes to `78` for `vary_DA` and so on until it finishes with `130` for `vary_DA`.

I have specific values of `min_aH` and `max_aH` for each of the `vary_DA` and `vary_Hinv` values.

```
min_aH = np.array([[24,30,30,30,30,30,30],[36,42,42,47,47,47,47],
                   [36,42,42,42,42,42,42],[36,42,42,42,42,42,42],
                   [42,47,47,47,53,47,53],[42,53,47,47,53,53,53],
                   [47,47,47,47,47,53,47],[47,47,47,47,47,59,59],
                   [53,53,59,59,59,59,64],[47,65,59,59,47,47,64],
                   [53,47,41,47,53,47,47],[36,41,41,41,53,47,47],
                   [36,36,41,41,53,47,47]]) 

# As you can see it is a 13x7 matrix, 7 for the 7 different vary_Hinv
# values and 13 for the 13 different vary_DA values    

max_aH = np.array([[54,60,60,60,60,60,60],[60,66,66,66,66,66,66],
                   [66,66,72,72,72,72,72],[66,72,72,72,78,78,78],
                   [72,78,78,78,84,84,84],[78,84,84,89,89,84,84],
                   [78,84,78,89,84,84,78],[84,84,78,84,84,89,89],
                   [84,84,84,89,89,89,89],[84,89,84,89,101,101,101],
                   [89,89,95,101,95,101,101],[96,96,95,107,95,101,101],
                   [96,101,95,107,107,101,101]])
```

**i.e. when `vary_DA = 70` and `vary_Hinv = 60`, `min_aH = 24` and `max_aH = 54`. 
when `vary_DA = 70` and `vary_Hinv = 76`, `min_aH = 30` and `max_aH = 60` and so on.**

Now I would like to use these specific values of `min_aH` and `max_aH` for the `for` loops, but as you can see from the below **working example** that it fails.

```
ii = 0

for vary_DA,test in zip(varying_DA,test_array): 

    jj = 0 

    for vary_Hinv,min_a,max_a in zip(varying_Hinv,min_aH,max_aH):

        print vary_DA,vary_Hinv,ii,jj,min_aH[ii][jj],max_aH[ii][jj]

        jj = jj + 1

ii = ii + 1
```

**IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.**

**BOTTOM LINE:**
When I can clearly do the following:

```
In [12]: min_aH[0]
Out[12]: array([24, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30])

In [13]: min_aH[0][0]
Out[13]: 24
```

Why does it fail in the `for` loop ? How do I get it to work ?

**EDIT**:

I have made a mistake in the above working example. In the second `for` loop, the `print` should have been:

```
print vary_DA,vary_Hinv,ii,jj,min_a[ii][jj],max_a[ii][jj]
```

I previously had `min_aH` and `max_aH` instead of `min_a` and `max_a`. Could someone please let me know if the above works?

Comment: I can get your code to run with no errors. Are your inputs exactly as in your question?

Comment: @jpp: doesn't it throw the IndexError at the `print` line ? i.e. the indices section

Comment: Added my full code as an answer (for lack of any better way). If you copy-paste, do you see an error? if you do, it's likely an issue with Python 2.7 v 3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few comments, firstly your example runs for me without the error using python 3, with output:

```
70 60 0 0 24 54
70 76 0 1 30 60
70 92 0 2 30 60
...
78 60 0 0 24 54
78 76 0 1 30 60
78 92 0 2 30 60
78 100 0 3 30 60
...
```

which I do not believe is what you desire because the last four rows should have different values for the last two numbers than the first four rows. I think what you want for the last four rows shown is:

```
78 60 1 0 36 60
78 76 1 1 42 66
78 92 1 2 42 66
78 100 1 3 47 66
```

based on your description. This is because the 
  ii = ii + 1 
is outside of your initial loop so ii does not change value at all the whole time. A working version (once again in python 3.6) would be:

```
ii = 0

for vary_DA,test in zip(varying_DA,test_array): 

    jj = 0 

    for vary_Hinv,min_a,max_a in zip(varying_Hinv,min_aH,max_aH):

        print (vary_DA,vary_Hinv,ii,jj,min_aH[ii][jj],max_aH[ii][jj])

        jj = jj + 1

    ii = ii + 1
```

Though this does not make use of the zipped values at all and if it attempted to the desired output would not be achieved. You can see here if I print out the zipped values you just get each list for the min_aH and max_aH but I believe you want the individual values.

```
ii = 0

for vary_DA,test in zip(varying_DA,test_array): 

    jj = 0 

    for vary_Hinv,min_a,max_a in zip(varying_Hinv,min_aH,max_aH):

        print (vary_DA,vary_Hinv,ii,jj,min_aH[ii][jj],max_aH[ii][jj],min_a,max_a)

        jj = jj + 1

    ii = ii + 1
```

Results in:

```
70 60 0 0 24 54 [24 30 30 30 30 30 30] [54 60 60 60 60 60 60]
70 76 0 1 30 60 [36 42 42 47 47 47 47] [60 66 66 66 66 66 66]
70 92 0 2 30 60 [36 42 42 42 42 42 42] [66 66 72 72 72 72 72]
...
78 60 1 0 36 60 [24 30 30 30 30 30 30] [54 60 60 60 60 60 60]
78 76 1 1 42 66 [36 42 42 47 47 47 47] [60 66 66 66 66 66 66]
78 92 1 2 42 66 [36 42 42 42 42 42 42] [66 66 72 72 72 72 72]
...
```

Finally a proper use of zip to get the values you desire, thus making the iterators, ii and jj, unnecessary, would be:

```
ii = 0
for vary_DA,test,min_a,max_a in zip(varying_DA,test_array,min_aH,max_aH): 

    jj = 0 

    for vary_Hinv,mn,mx in zip(varying_Hinv,min_a,max_a):

        print (vary_DA,vary_Hinv,ii,jj,min_aH[ii][jj],max_aH[ii][jj],mn,mx)

        jj = jj + 1
    ii = ii + 1
```

giving:

```
70 60 0 0 24 54 24 54
70 76 0 1 30 60 30 60
70 92 0 2 30 60 30 60
...
78 60 1 0 36 60 36 60
78 76 1 1 42 66 42 66
78 92 1 2 42 66 42 66
...
```

as desired, finally removing the iterators it looks like this:

```
for vary_DA,test,min_a,max_a in zip(varying_DA,test_array,min_aH,max_aH): 
    for vary_Hinv,mn,mx in zip(varying_Hinv,min_a,max_a):
        print (vary_DA,vary_Hinv,mn,mx)
```

And that should work as desired.

I also was able to successfully run both your sample code and my response using python 2.7 , so I am not sure why you are getting that error based on what is here.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on Python 3.6:

```
varying_DA = [70,78,86,90,94,98,100,102,106,110,114,122,130]
test_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13] #DUMMY array
varying_Hinv = [60,76,92,100,108,124,140]

min_aH = np.array([[24,30,30,30,30,30,30],[36,42,42,47,47,47,47],
                   [36,42,42,42,42,42,42],[36,42,42,42,42,42,42],
                   [42,47,47,47,53,47,53],[42,53,47,47,53,53,53],
                   [47,47,47,47,47,53,47],[47,47,47,47,47,59,59],
                   [53,53,59,59,59,59,64],[47,65,59,59,47,47,64],
                   [53,47,41,47,53,47,47],[36,41,41,41,53,47,47],
                   [36,36,41,41,53,47,47]]) 

max_aH = np.array([[54,60,60,60,60,60,60],[60,66,66,66,66,66,66],
                   [66,66,72,72,72,72,72],[66,72,72,72,78,78,78],
                   [72,78,78,78,84,84,84],[78,84,84,89,89,84,84],
                   [78,84,78,89,84,84,78],[84,84,78,84,84,89,89],
                   [84,84,84,89,89,89,89],[84,89,84,89,101,101,101],
                   [89,89,95,101,95,101,101],[96,96,95,107,95,101,101],
                   [96,101,95,107,107,101,101]]) 

ii = 0

for vary_DA,test in zip(varying_DA,test_array): 

    jj = 0 

    for vary_Hinv,min_a,max_a in zip(varying_Hinv,min_aH,max_aH):

        print(vary_DA,vary_Hinv,ii,jj,min_aH[ii][jj],max_aH[ii][jj])

        jj = jj + 1

ii = ii + 1
```